# How to write a small "dash" in superscript using MathJax

Tags: support, mathjax

Specifically, I am trying to write this:

Ignore whether the term is mathematically correct or not. Can someone help?
[image: infinity/infinitydash]

Comment: $\frac\infty{\infty'}$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, thank you very much.

Comment: From the table of contents in the question:  [Symbols](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11284/) (for determining how to write an infinity); fractions are described in the question ([CTRL]+[F] for "fractions").  The tick for "prime" is not described in the FAQ, but it should be intuitive to figure out (i.e. `'`).

Comment: Actually the ' is already a superscript: `$\infty^\prime = \infty'$`$\infty^\prime = \infty'$

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes, i noticed that too.

Comment: I would never criticize someone who's having trouble figuring out just exactly which intuitive things work on LaTeX and which don't.

Comment: I think I left this out of [the quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), perhaps unintentionally. I wonder if it's useful enough to add it?

Comment: @MJD Although the dash in superscript isn't used as much as other symbols are, it would still be useful to have it in the quick reference page, maybe somewhere in a "Miscellaneous" column.

Comment: I put it in the same section with superscripts. I thought it could go there, or with the diacritical marks, but that it was commonly-enough used that I should put it closer to the beginning, so with the superscripts and subscripts.